# Setup add function in Mock DbSet with Moq (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, xunit

I'm new to mocking, and I'm trying to create a mock **DbContext** for testing select, add, update, delete.

The mock for selecting is working, but when I'm trying to add the '**add**' function in the setup, I'm getting the following error in my return value `.Returns((CalculatieInput t) => t)`:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'DK.Infrastructure.CalculatieInput' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<DK.Infrastructure.CalculatieInput>
```

**Test.cs:**

```
    [Fact]
    public void Add1()
    {
        var context = CreateDbContext();
        _da = new CalculatieInputDA(context.Object);

        CalculatieInput item = new CalculatieInput() { Title = "add test" };

        _da.Add(item);

        List<CalculatieInput> list = _da.getAll();

        Assert.Equal(27, list.Count);
    }

    private Mock<dieKeureWebContext> CreateDbContext()
    {
        var data = GetFakeData().AsQueryable();

        var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<CalculatieInput>>();
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<CalculatieInput>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<CalculatieInput>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<CalculatieInput>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<CalculatieInput>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        dbSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<CalculatieInput>())).Returns((CalculatieInput t) => t);

        var context = new Mock<dieKeureWebContext>();
        context.Setup(c => c.CalculatieInput).Returns(dbSet.Object);

        return context;
    }

    private IEnumerable<CalculatieInput> GetFakeData()
    {
        var i = 1;
        var data = A.ListOf<CalculatieInput>(26);
        data.ForEach(x => x.Id = i++);
        return data.Select(_ => _);
    }
```

**CalculatieInputDA.cs**:

```
    public CalculatieInput Add(CalculatieInput item)
    {
        _context.CalculatieInput.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return item;
    }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction how to fix this?

Comment: Add should be a void :  public void Add(CalculatieInput item)

Comment: @jdweng: I need the returnvalue (with Id) for my frontend/broadcast service.

Comment: You are returning the same value that is in the parameter list. The service should have the value already.

Comment: is this .net core?  Why not use the in-memory provider in your tests  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

Comment: @jdweng: that doesn't remove the error.

Comment: @fran: That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe this link cna help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72743897/setup-add-function-in-mock-of-a-dbset-entity-framawork-to-change-vale-of-a-objec