# Setup add function in mock of a DbSet Entity framawork to change vale of a object property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, callback, moq, addition

if you use an add function, then the property id of the element to include will be changed for a value assign from the table, How can i to do this?.

Answer (score 0):

First. create a generic class that define the operations:

```
public static Mock<DbSet<T>> SetupMockDbSet<T>(IList<T> dataToBeReturnedOnGet) where T : class
    {
        var mocks = dataToBeReturnedOnGet.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(mocks.Provider));
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(mocks.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(mocks.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(mocks.GetEnumerator());
        mockSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => ModifiedProcess(s));
        mockSet.As<IAsyncEnumerable<T>>()
            .Setup(x => x.GetAsyncEnumerator(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .Returns(new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(mocks.GetEnumerator()));

        return mockSet;
    }
```

The function add use Callback, who can access to parameters sended, and after define a function who has a process that depend of the object sended

```
public static void ModifiedProcess<T>(T parameter) where T : class
    {
        if (parameter is ObjectDTO)
        {
            ObjectDTO obj2 = (ObjectDTO)Convert.ChangeType(parameter, typeof(ObjectDTO));
            obj2.Id = 5;
        }
    }
```